# Because someone has already answered I can't delete my question even it was closed and everyone considers it is not appropriate

Tags: support

I had opened this question [I feel like the tech industry is increasingly calling for pragmatism and I'm just bad at it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448830/i-feel-like-the-tech-industry-is-increasingly-calling-for-pragmatism-and-im-jus). It was rapidly downvoted multiple times and closed. I concluded that it does not belong to stackexchange. The website is even showing me a banner to delete it. After a few days, I decided to delete it in order to move it to a forum. At this moment I surprisingly found that, despite what the banner proposes, I cannot remove it because at least one answer has already been provided.

I understand that this restriction has been added to prevent the original poster from removing both somebody else's contribution and interesting information that future readers may want to read about. But in the current case it seems everybody agrees that the question is not appropriate anyway. I suppose nobody will be looking for an answer to a question that is considered of no interest.

Can I ask a moderator to delete it?

Comment: *"it seems everybody agrees that the question is not appropriate anyway"* - obviously not *anybody* agress. As far as I can see this question got 3 upvotes and a detailed answer. Disclaimer: I did not vote on this question before. Now, as you asked for it, I voted to delete it, with a 3rd vote I think it will be deleted, regardless of the existing answer.

Comment: ... let me add your question might be fine for "The Workplace".

Comment: Would it really be more suited to "The Workplace" ? I aimed at focusing on potential skill issues for a specific job (software engineers). It seems that the Work Place is clearly more on general career, legal, team aspects.
On the other question of reactions from softwareengineering.stackechange, sure some people seem to be more positive. But the question was still closed with even more negative reactions. So overall the message is: this is not the place. Or what are you suggesting ?

Comment: Now the fact is that [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) is still considered a bad practice on stack exchange. So if I chose "The Workplace" it seems I should make sure the question is deleted here first.

Comment: Not sure about the question beeing appropriate for the Workplace, it was just an idea.  I flagged your question for deletion by a mod, but got no reaction. Maybe it helps if you flag it, too? I will also comment on the question to draw more attention to this meta post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question in stake was deleted by a mod in between.